# plotly.js axis 'anchor' attribute

Tags: plotly

I'm trying to customize some subplots, but I don't understand what the axis 'anchor' attribute means.

Some examples where this attribute is used are here: https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/ . What does `yaxis2: {anchor: 'x2'}` mean? What does `anchor=false`, or `anchor=free` mean? I haven't been able to find an explanation in the online docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found the documentation on the axis `anchor`attribute [here](https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/reference/#xaxis-anchor).

An x axis can be anchored to a y axis, for example `xaxis2: {anchor: 'y2'}`means that xaxis2 joins yaxis2 at the origin. If `anchor`is set to `free`, the position attribute can then be used to move the axis at another [position](https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/reference/#xaxis-position).

I'm not sure whether setting `anchor=false` is even possible, I saw that used in the `make_subplots` function of the plotly.py API [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/892d0c804d5adc3f27a2e79983cd495a6f132ede/plotly/tools.py), but it may be that `false`is just a value used by the python API internally.

Comment: I have seen: anchor='free'

Answer (score 7):

Although the anchor mechanism is quite simple, seeing a schema from the start would have saved me a lot of time.

So here's a visual explanation of how subplot axes can be handled in 2D. Each pointed arrow represents an "*is anchored to*" relationship

[image]

Sketch based on [the official example](https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/#multiple-subplots).

Comment: side note: in the end, since I'm generating subplots dynamically, I ended up double-anchoring axes in every subplot. more simple, and works fine :)

Comment: If anyone else is wondering what this diagram is saying, you need to compare it side by side with the shared axes diagram at the [offical example link](https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-axes).