# Plotly axes are behaving very strangely between subplots. Whats going on and how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Here is a [link to an Nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/clockelliptic/natl_abstr_18/blob/pub/Relearn/Axes_probs.ipynb) showing the issues with the Plotly graph.

Notice first off that the top two sine function plots have their y-axes on the left-hand side of the round polar graph. Notice also that neither of them have any apparent x-axis.

Notice also that the bottom two graphs are sharing (in a very odd way--try to use it to slide side to side on the graph) an x-axis.

I have tried to give them more spacing. I feel certain that is not the issue. The figure's axes are all anchored correctly. I honestly don't have the slightest clue why these are getting mixed up, and any help or feedback would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Also note that the traces `l4` and `l5` are both intended to be graphed on the same set of axes. This is not a mistake.

Here is my code:

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode()

import numpy as np

pi = np.pi

# Define our frequencies
f1, f2 = 2, 6

# generate wave function and data
T = np.linspace(0, 2 * pi, 44100)


def wav(f, t): return np.sin(np.dot(f, t))


def r(t): return wav(f1, t) - wav(f2, t)


# Plot each of the subplots
l0 = go.Scatterpolar(
    r=r(T), theta=np.linspace(0, 360, 44100), 
     name="Rosette Trace")
l1 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=r(T), xaxis="x1", yaxis="y1", name="Perceived Wave")
l2 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f1, T), xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2", name="Wave 1")
l3 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f2, T), xaxis="x3", yaxis="y3", name="Wave 2")
l4 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f1, T), xaxis="x4", yaxis="y4", name="Waves_12")
l5 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f2, T), xaxis="x4", yaxis="y4", name="waves_12")

# Which subplots will be plotted
data = [l0, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]


layout = go.Layout(

    # Set position and layout of Polar graph
    # 'domain' controls position and relative size of subplots
    polar=dict(
        domain=dict(x=[0.0, 0.35], y=[0.5, 1]),
        angularaxis=dict(thetaunit="radians"),
        radialaxis=dict(range=[-2, 2.1])),

    # Set positions and layouts of wave function graphs
    # 'domain' controls position and relative size of subplots
    xaxis1=dict(anchor="x1", domain=[0, 1]),
    yaxis1=dict(anchor="y1", domain=[0.25, 0.45]),

    xaxis2=dict(anchor="x2", domain=[0.5, 1]),
    yaxis2=dict(anchor="y2", domain=[0.8, 1]),

    xaxis3=dict(anchor="x3", domain=[0.5, 1]),
    yaxis3=dict(anchor="y3", domain=[0.55, 0.75]),

    xaxis4=dict(anchor="x4", domain=[0, 1]),
    yaxis4=dict(anchor="y4", domain=[0, 0.2]),

    # Set layout options for entire figure
    margin=dict(r=40, t=45, b=40, l=60),
    title='Fancy Title',
    height=625,
    showlegend=False
)


# Define a variable containing the entire figure of plots
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Make it happen!
py.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I discovered [via this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489942/plotly-js-axis-anchor-attribute#37492953) that the anchor attribute needed to be used differently, such that yaxis1 is anchored to x1, and xaxis1 is anchored to y1:

```
    # Plot each of the subplots
l0 = go.Scatterpolar(                # converts radians to degrees, but can
    r=r(T), theta=T*(360/(2*np.pi))) # also use np.linspace(0, 360, 44100))
l1 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=r(T), xaxis="x1", yaxis="y1", name="Perceived Wave")
l2 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f1, T), xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2", name="Wave 1")
l3 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f2, T), xaxis="x3", yaxis="y3", name="Wave 2")
l4 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f1, T), xaxis="x4", yaxis="y4", name="Waves_12")
l5 = go.Scatter(x=T, y=wav(f2, T), xaxis="x4", yaxis="y4", name="waves_12")
```

This fixes the problem.